# Convert .NET library to use in Windows Phone 7 (Here I need Google API library)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

currently I'm working on a Windows Phone App and I want to use the Google API for OAuth and Calendar. Unfortunately, it's not possible to import Google's ddl files, giving me an error that it is a .NET library and not a specific Wndows Phone library.

I haven't found anyone trying to convert the Google API files especially for WIndows Phone - does anyone know sth about this?

Or is there any kind of converter for .NET libraries to Windows Phone libraries?

Or is there any other possibility that I can use the Google libraries in my Windows Phone project? I don't really want to implement the OAuth2 stuff by myself and it would be nice to have the Calendar API :)

Comment: Microsoft has an OAuth 2.0 SDK they have released I would use that. Google also has a .NET Wrapper for most of their services which have an generic SDK.

Answer (score 0):

install nuget, open your windows phone 7.1 project and rightclick reference manage nugget, search for GDATA, you should find what you are looking for.